# "pip install mysqlclient" throws error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the mysqlclient module in python 2.7. Using pip and easy_install give the following error

```
> easy_install mysqlclient


Searching for mysqlclient
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/
Best match: mysqlclient 1.3.12
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2
adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz#sha256=2d9ec33d
e39f4d9c64ad7322ede0521d85829ce36a76f9dd3d6ab76a9c8648e5
Processing mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\home\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-9oa3ct\mysqlclient-1.3.12\
setup.cfg
Running mysqlclient-1.3.12\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\home\appdat
a\local\temp\easy_install-9oa3ct\mysqlclient-1.3.12\egg-dist-tmp-kxvslf
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

The same error also with pip.
I understand that some modules contain C code and need to be compiled before installation so i installed [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) and added the location of **vcvarsall.bat** to a new system environmental variable **VS90COMNTOOLS** (Other answers show that this is where pip searches for the location of vcvarsall.bat) but i am still getting the same error.

Do i need to add it's path somewhere else? Where do pip and easy_install search for the file before starting compilation? How do i resolve this error?

Comment: Did you start a new shell after installing the C++ compliler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: yes , i did start a new shell.

Comment: Where do pip or easy_install search for the file?

Answer (score 0):

What solved for me was using :

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```